# How store a tree in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, tree

Suppose I need to store a forest of trees in a Mongo. Let's consider the following tree for example (in practice, trees are much larger)

```
.
├── a
│   └── a1
├── b
│   ├── b1
│   └── b2
└── c
```

I will need to add/remove/rename nodes and retrieve nodes by parent in the original order, for example

```
add "a/a1" to root
add "a/a2" to root
add "a/a3" to root
remove "a/a3" from root
rename "a/a2" to "a/a3" in root
```

I want to store tree nodes as documents in collection `nodes`. Every node document contains the `name`, `parentId`, and `order` among its "siblings".

```
{ _id:0, "name":".",  "parentId":0, "order":0 }
{ _id:1, "name":"a",  "parentId":0, "order":0 }
{ _id:2, "name":"a1", "parentId":1, "order":0 }
{ _id:3, "name":"b",  "parentId":0, "order":1 }
{ _id:4, "name":"b1", "parentId":3, "order":0 }
{ _id:4, "name":"b2", "parentId":3, "order":1 }
{ _id:4, "name":"c",  "parentId":0, "order":2 }
```

Does this schema make sense ? How would you improve it ? Would you suggest an alternative ?

Comment: Intuitively, I will store the ids of child nodes in an array of parent nodes to avoid iterating full whole collection(even with indexing) to search for list of child nodes. I will keep the parentId field to trace back the parent node from a child node; while leaving out the order field as your use cases seem not to focus on working with siblings.

Comment: Some details at: [Model Tree Structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) with MongoDB.